# Connectedness of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I want to examine whether this subspace is connected or not:

$$
([0, 1) \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\{1\} \times \mathbb{Z}) \subset \mathbb{R}^2
$$

I am not sure if my reasoning is correct:

1. The two sets are disjoint. If I am able to show that they are open in the subspace topology, then the subspace is not connected. However, I fail to show that these two sets are open or not (how can we do this systematically in the subspace topology of a product topology?).
2. We could check whether the subspace is path-connected. This would require to show that the union of the two sets is convex. Since the union results in $([0, 1] \times \mathbb{R}) $, the union is convex and therefore path-connected and it follows that the subspace is connected.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried sketching the space? What can you say about $[0,1) \cup \{1\}$?

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake: $([0, 1) \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\{1\} \times \mathbb{Z}) \neq ([0, 1] \times \mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union is connected because it is path-connected. However, it is not path-connected because it is convex.

The union would "look like a saw" with the right edge of the strip solid only on integer points (points like $(1,0), (1,1)$ and so on, but not $(1,\frac{1}{2})$ ). That being said, the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$ is not contained in the union, so its not convex.

The union is path-connected since for any two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, they are connected by the path $[(a,b), (0,b), (0, d), (c,d)]$, which is a three-part path connecting the two points.

So back to your points, point 1 is a method to prove disconnectedness but not really useful here since $\{1\}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is closed and not open. Point 2 is in the right direction but the deduction needs more careful consideration, as stated above.